# Using Python Repositories in Swift for iOS app

Tags: python, swift, xcode, module, repository

I need to import a repository on GitHub called populartimes located here https://github.com/m-wrzr/populartimes into swift for an iOS app for iPhone. I tried importing pythonkit to run scripts, but actually importing the repository onto my project leads to errors:

[image]

I'm not sure if I should copy the repository or pip install it and to make sure the python file knows what the import is.

Attempting to import the module after installing the dependancy package to project:

[image]

I'm not sure if it installed correctly. If anyone knows how to install it properly, if there is even a way that'll be appreciated.